# Changing values of font variation setting doesn't have any effect

Tags: html, css, fonts

Im new to font variation settings. Tried to bootstrap it but got stuck.

**HTML USED**
`<p> Regular font</p>`

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
    font-family: "Lato";
    src: url("Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
html{
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-variation-settings: "wght" 800;
}
```

**Output rendered**

Just lato font rendered changing variation settings value doesn't have any effect.

Not sure why this isn't working. I downloaded the font from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato

Appreciate your help. Thanks, in advance